# Can't access website via cURL from localhost, but can from hosted server

Tags: php, xml, curl, screen-scraping

I'm writing a script that pulls XML data from wowarmory.com, using PHP 5 and cURL:

```
$url = "http://www.wowarmory.com";
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$str  = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
$str .= "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n";
$str .= "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n";
$str .= "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n";
$str .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($str));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3000);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
```

When I run this from my hosted web server, I get the XML response as expected. But when running from my localhost web server, I get nothing.

I can get any other website via cURL from localhost ( yahoo.com, even worldofwarcraft.com ), but not wowarmory.com. So I know cURL is functioning properly.

I'm using the following versions of PHP and cURL:

Hosted Server:

- php 5.2.6
- cURL libcurl/7.16.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7e zlib/1.2.3

Localhost:

- php 5.2.6
- cURL libcurl/7.16.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8i zlib/1.2.3

Any ideas?

EDIT: Localhost is running Windows XP SP3. I can access wowarmory.com through a web browser. Tracert starts timing out at hop 13 ( from my location, obviously ):

```
13   458 ms   529 ms   549 ms  0.so-6-0-0.BR1.LAX15.ALTER.NET [152.63.116.21]
14   476 ms   510 ms   488 ms  192.205.34.29
15   257 ms   279 ms   261 ms  cr1.la2ca.ip.att.net [12.122.128.14]
16   242 ms   259 ms   249 ms  gar5.la2ca.ip.att.net [12.122.128.25]
17   252 ms     *     1691 ms  12.122.255.74
18     *     2361 ms   634 ms  mdf001c7613r0003-gig-10-1.lax1.attens.net [12.129.193.242]
19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I'm not familiar with tcptraceroute, unfortunately.

The windows binary version of curl doesn't return anything for http://www.wowarmory.com/ but does for http://www.yahoo.com/

I don't have wget available.

EDIT 2: I can access my localhosted website just fine. It's just the response from curl I don't receive. I'm running a pretty much default XAMPP install ( apache 2 on windows xp ). All of this works fine.

Comment: Can you access your site through http://localhost in a web browser? If your web server isn't responding to localhost requests then it's not going to work just because you try using cURL. What web server are we talking about and how is it set up?

Comment: Does echo curl_error($ch); return anything?

Answer (score 2):

Can you access it from your local host via a web browser or even via the `curl` or `wget` command line utilities?

What does `tcptraceroute` tell you?

If neither a web browser nor the command line utility work, but `tcptraceroute` works (and does not show a transparent proxy somewhere in the way), and you are behind a DSL link, it is possible that your problem is a [PMTU blackhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMTU_blackhole). If that is the case, the workaround is [MSS clamping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSS_clamping).

Answer (score 0):

api's probably give responses back to some URL (say nextUrl or currentUrl). if your URL is localhost or a local system IP address, how and where an api response back to..? Coz the api will response back to the nextUrl() or currentUrl(). So please use a permanent IP or domain name to work.